# How to create a proper custom exception class?

Tags: java, oop, exception

I am trying to create a custom exception class and I'm having a lot of trouble. Can someone help me out! I just started programming very recently and i'm hoping to get some pointers.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class GuessingGame {

    public static void main(String[]args) throws BadGuessException
    {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 10;
        Random rand = new Random();

        int numberToGuess = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;    

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;
        boolean win = false; 
        int numberOfTries = 0;

        while (!win) 
        {

            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
            try
            {
                guess = input.nextInt();
                numberOfTries++;


                if (guess == numberToGuess)
                {       
                    win = true;
                    System.out.println("YOU GOT IT!");
                    System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tires.");

                }
                else
                {
                    throw new BadGuessException();
                }
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e)
            {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

}


    import java.util.*;

public class BadGuessException extends Exception {

    String message = "Sorry, that was an invalid guess!";

    //Default Constructor 
    public BadGuessException()
    {
        super();
    }

    //Parameterized Constructor
    public BadGuessException(Throwable cause)         
    {  
      super(cause);        
    }      

}
```

I'm supposed to create 2 constructors, one default and one parametrized. If the user enters a number between 1-10, i should catch it in a catch block and print the message "invalid guess" And if they enter a letter or something, the output should be something like "Invalid input" ( Should I catch invalid input in BadGuessException and then pass it to InputMismmatch? If so, how do I do that?)
Right now, when I run this code, if I enter a letter, it doesn't crash, but the while loop iterates continuously and I'm not able to enter anymore inputs. It just keeps repeating "Guess a number between 1-10."

I'm assuming it's because once the try block executes once, it doesn't execute again? How do I fix this? Sorry for any confusion, happy to clarify! any help is much appreciated.

Also, I'm not sure how to catch 2 different exceptions at the same time. One for invalid guess and one for invalid input. :/

Comment: How are two exceptions supposed to be thrown at the same time?

Comment: You're almost there. Just add a `catch ( BadGuessException e ) { System.out.println( e.getMessage() ); }` below the `catch` that's already there (also: `e.getMessage();` on itself doesn't do anything, you'll want to print it!). Idk about scanner but perhaps you need to `input.next()` to fetch (and discard) that letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exceptions should be used for handling errors, invalid input, illegal, unusual situations. If not guessing the correct number is an error, that sounds like not being a mind reader is an error. So `BadGuessException` is misused here.

For a better use case, how about throwing this exception for non-sense input? For example, since the program asks the user to input a number between 1 and 10, inputting -3 or 99 would be clearly an error.

The loop in the middle can be corrected accordingly:

```
while (!win) {
    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
    try {
        guess = input.nextInt();
        numberOfTries++;

        if (guess == numberToGuess) {
            win = true;
            System.out.println("YOU GOT IT!");
            System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tires.");
        } else if (guess < 1 || guess > 10) {
            throw new BadGuessException();
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

As for creating a custom exception class, you already did that. It's written a bit messy way, cleaning it up (removing unnecessary stuff) it becomes:

```
public class BadGuessException extends Exception {

    private static final String message = "Sorry, that was an invalid guess!";

    public BadGuessException() {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE

I fixed another bug in your code: if you enter non-integer input, a `InputMismatchException` will be thrown. Repeatedly. Forever.
This is because the `input.nextInt()` *doesn't consume* the input if it's not valid. So the invalid input stays there, and `input.nextInt()` will keep failing, putting your program in an infinite loop.

To fix that, you must consume the bad input somehow, for example by reading the line:

```
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        input.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: I wanted to create a parametrized constructor also. But when i looked at the documentation for Exception, it seems that you can have multiple parameters. Which parameters would I use? Just a type Throwable? or a String?

Comment: Use just what you need, nothing more. If you don't need anything else, don't add anything else. In this example, there's really need to for a `Throwable`

Comment: WHen I do e.getMessage inside a print statement, it says cannot find symbol

Comment: So when I catch the InputMismatch exception, the code never goes back to the asking me for an input, it just repeats "guess again" continually. (I posted the comment in more detail in ControlAltDel's answer. Can you please help me clarify this?

Comment: Oh I see. I have a fix and explanation for that, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is if they make a guess and it is incorrect, that your loop should run again, right? In that case, you should adjust your loop, as I've shown below. Also, where you are catching the InputMismatchException, you are swallowing the exception without printing it or handling it: This is VERY BAD PRACTICE. I've updated this too for you.

```
while (!win) 
        {

            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
            try
            {
                guess = input.nextInt();
                numberOfTries++;

                win=true;

                if (guess == numberToGuess)
                {       
                    win = true;
                    System.out.println("YOU GOT IT!");
                    System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTries + " tires.");

                }
                else
                {
                    throw new BadGuessException();
                }
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Please input a number betwee 1 and 10!");
            }
            catch(BadGuessException ex) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, you guessed the wrong number!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello, thakn you so much! that catches the wrong input, however, when I input a letter, it repeats continuously. It doesn't ask me for another input again. :/ (I removed the win = true about the if statement) That error was a silly mistake on my part.

Comment: When I enter a letter, the program goes into an infinite loop and displays the following messages continually and never asks me for an input "Guess a number between 1 and 10:
Please input a number between 1 and 10!"  @ControlAltDel

Answer (score 0):

You never catch the BadGuessException so it will be thrown out of the while loop and program will exit. You must catch the exception inside the loop if you want to continue.

I agree with janos comment that this is not a good use of exceptions. Guessing wrong is part of the normal game flow, no?

But doing it for the practice, I'd for example pull all logic inside the loop into a new private method, let it throw this exception, and catch it in the loop. You can catch multiple exceptions in a row like this.

```
while (!win) {
    try {
        win = makeGuess();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            e.getMessage();
    }  catch (BadGuessException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong guess");
    } 
}

private boolean makeGuess() throws BadGuessException, InputMismatchException {
   ...
 }
```